# Explain the Anaconda folder structure

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, directory, file-structure

Can someone please explain the Anaconda folder structure?

Every search I do just points me to an explanation of how to create Python packages, and the `conda` [docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/concepts.html) don't seem to explain very much aside from `.\pkgs` and `.\envs`. I would like to gain a better understanding of what the purpose of each folder is and what sorts of files should go there. For example, why are there files that appear to be duplicates in different folders (e.g. `.\Library\bin\git.exe` vs. `.\pkgs\git-2.17.0-hb9891f8_1\Library\bin\git.exe`)?

Answer (score 6):

When you install for the first time the conda, all packages will be extracted to the `pkgs` folder and all these packages are available when you use conda. Let's just say it's like a local repository for conda, the default environment you have is linked to all these packages.

When you decide to create your customized environment, this environment will be create under `envs` and only the packages you've chosen to install in this environment will be linked to `pkgs` packages.

This answer is not exhaustive and need more improvements, it just gives you a little insight about your question.

Comment: "the default environment you have is linked to all these packages" This is not quite correct. The default environment is only linked to the packages that are installed in that environment, just like any other environment.

Comment: Do you know any links that may explain this a bit more?